# Writing an If condition to filter out the first word

Tags: python, string, search

I have a string:

> Father ate a banana and slept on a feather

Part of my code shown below:

```
...

if word.endswith(('ther')):
   print word
```

This prints `feather` and also `Father`

But i want to modify this `if condition` so it doesn't apply this search for the first word of a sentence. So the result should only print `feather`.

I tried having `and` but it didn't work:

```
...

if word.endswith(('ther')) and word[0].endswith(('ther')):
   print word
```

This doesn't work. HELP

Comment: Do you only want to skip the first word in the sentence?

Comment: What if there are more tan 2 such words?

Comment: why don't you put all the words that matched into an array and if length is > 1 you simply print the array without first position.

Comment: Isn't there any other option to append to my existing `if` condition ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a range to skip first word and apply the `endswith()` function to the rest of words, like:

```
s = 'Father ate a banana and slept on a feather'
[w for w in s.split()[1:] if w.endswith('ther')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(\w*ther)',s)[1:]
['feather']
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, you don't want it to print the word if it's the first word in the string. So, you could copy the string and drop the first word.

I'll walk you through it. Say you have this string:

`s = "Father ate a banana and slept on a feather"`

You can split it by running `s.split()` and catching that output:

`['Father', 'ate', 'a', 'banana', 'and', 'slept', 'on', 'a', 'feather']`

So if you want all the words, except the first, you can use the index `[1:]`. And you can combine the list of words by joining with a space.

`s1 = "Father ate a banana and slept on a feather"
s2 = " ".join(s1.split()[1:])`

The string `s2` will now be the following:

`ate a banana and slept on a feather`

You can use that string and iterate over the words like you did above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid making a temporary string

```
[w for i, w in enumerate(s.split()) if w.endswith('ther') and i]
```